# Export .MWB to working .SQL file using command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, mysql-workbench, forward-engineer

> We recently installed a server dedicated to unit tests, which deploys
>   updates automatically via Jenkins when commits are done, and sends
>   mails when a regression is noticed
>   
>  > *This requires our database to always be up-to-date*
>
> Since the database-schema-reference is our MWB, we added some scripts
>   during deploy, which export the .mwb to a .sql (using python) This
>   worked fine... but still has some issues

Our main concern is that **the functions attached to the schema are not exported at all**, which makes the DB unusable.

We'd like to hack into the python code to make it export scripts... but didn't find enough informations about it.
Here is the only piece of [documentation](http://mysqlworkbench.org/workbench/doc/globals/classes.html) we found.  It's not very clear for us.  We didn't find any information about exporting scripts.

All we found is that a db_Script class exists.  We don't know *where* we can find its instances in our execution context, nor if they *can* be exported easily.  Did we miss something ?

For reference, here is the script we currently use for the mwb to sql conversion (mwb2sql.sh).

*It calls the MySqlWorkbench from command line (we use a dummy x-server to flush graphical output.)

What we need to complete is the python part passed in our command-line call of workbench.*

```
# generate sql from mwb
# usage: sh mwb2sql.sh {mwb file} {output file}
# prepare: set env MYSQL_WORKBENCH

if [ "$MYSQL_WORKBENCH" = "" ]; then
  export MYSQL_WORKBENCH="/usr/bin/mysql-workbench"
fi

export INPUT=$(cd $(dirname $1);pwd)/$(basename $1)
export OUTPUT=$(cd $(dirname $2);pwd)/$(basename $2)

"$MYSQL_WORKBENCH" \
  --open $INPUT \
  --run-python "
import os
import grt
from grt.modules import DbMySQLFE as fe
c = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog
fe.generateSQLCreateStatements(c, c.version, {})
fe.createScriptForCatalogObjects(os.getenv('OUTPUT'), c, {})" \
  --quit-when-done
set -e
```

Comment: Were you able to generate sql script from command line

Comment: @npr Sadly, not.  We are still waiting for a working tool for that, since the export I'm speaking of here is currently incomplete/broken.
In the meantime, we continue to do things manually... with the drawbacks it implies.